# How to localize an NSString defined in iOS's AddressBook framework?

Tags: ios, localization

How can you localize the value of an NSString defined in a system framework?

Eg: `NSString *kABPersonAddressStreetKey` is defined in the `AddressBook` framework and the value of it is `Street`.

Comment: Have you tried to change device locale and check which langue this string will be? I think that is may be localized...?

Comment: Well, these are keys for internal use... There should be no need for localizing them.

Comment: OK, I found it. Documentation doesn't seem to mention this, but you can pass these string keys to `ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(CFStringRef label)` to get them localized.